# Exchange Google token for IdentityServer token

Tags: android, identityserver4

I've setup an instance of Identity Server 4 and enabled an Authorization code grant for a client.  I can easily log into a my c# MVC app using this grant.  I also have an Android app that I'd like to tie to it as well.  Ideally, I'd be able to use the native Google/Facebook login mechanisms so that the users get the best experience.  But, if I use those, I got a Google/Facebook token, not a token sourced from Identity Server, which creates authorization problems when talking to our APIs on behalf of the user.

Is there some mechanism that I can use in Identity Server that will allow me to exchange that Google/Facebook token for an Identity Server token?  Is this even a good idea?

The Stack Exchange app does this, but I can't say for sure what technologies it uses behind the scenes.  I guess the TL;DR; is that I want to emulate the Stack Exchange app login workflow using my app and Identity Server but need a little direction on the native login side of things.

See Stack Exchange login workflow below.

[image]

After clicking "Log In":

[image]
Clicking Google or Facebook displays the native login screen.  Clicking Log In with another OpenId redirects you to the standard login, loaded via browser.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Even the official docs have an [example](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html) for the google integration 
it will look something like

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        options.ClientId = "...";
        options.ClientSecret = "...";
    })
```

and trigger the call with

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback");

var props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
    Items =
    {
        { "scheme", provider },
        { "returnUrl", returnUrl }
    }
};

return Challenge(provider, props);
```

Eventually it will accept the token generated by Google as its own. Also you can use it for your own external ways of auth - Facebook, Twitter etc.

hope it helps.